# Manage error handling with seedstack and undertow

Tags: error-handling, undertow, seedstack

I need to manage HTTP errors, by seting up a generic error message, in order to hide server side errors in the HTTP response.

I'm using Seedstack and the embeded server undertow. I've found how manage the errors using HttpHandler, I just didn't found yet how integrate this error handler to SeedStack.

My SimpleErrorPageHandler

```java
public class SimpleErrorPageHandler implements HttpHandler {

    private final HttpHandler next;

    public SimpleErrorPageHandler(final HttpHandler next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(final HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.addDefaultResponseListener(exchange1 -> {
            if (!exchange1.isResponseChannelAvailable()) {
                return false;
            }
            if (exchange1.getStatusCode() == 500) {
                final String errorPage = "<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Internal Error</body></html>";
                exchange1.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_LENGTH, "" + errorPage.length());
                exchange1.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html");
                Sender sender = exchange1.getResponseSender();
                sender.send(errorPage);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        next.handleRequest(exchange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of SeedStack doesn't allow to define custom Undertow HTTP handler. Only the HTTP handler for servlet support is hard-coded. We plan to introduce [the capability](https://github.com/seedstack/seed/issues/264) in the future.

However, regarding your question, we [just merged](https://github.com/seedstack/seed/pull/267) the ability to specify error pages for specific HTTP status codes or exceptions, as well as a default error page. This will be done like that:

```
web:
  server:
    errorPages:
      - location: /errors/404.html
        errorCode: 404
      - location: /errors/415.html
        errorCode: 415
      - location: /errors/default.html
```

This feature will be released in the upcoming SeedStack 19.7, at the end of July.